How Make the Snack Bar displayed in any currently active screen in flutter based on state change
I tried to display the error message built with the ConnBloc class using Flutter Bloc state management, and I implemented the BlocListner. When the state changes it displays the current state in the active screen, but the error message is not displayed in the currently active screen, however, the bloc is correctly implemented and displays the error in the console for checking purposes, but not displayed on screen.
How to make snackbar message displayed in one of these ways if possible:
1. display in  HomeMainScreen,SecondScreen, or HaveNews classes listed in bottom navigation bar
2. in any currently active  screen
The code looks like this
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  int pageIndex = 0;

  final pages = const [
    HomeMainScreen(),
    SecondScreen(),
    HaveNews(),
  ];

  int _selectedTab = 0;
  _changeTab(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedTab = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
        leading: const Icon(Icons.logo_dev),
        title: "Hello Dev"
       
            
              ),
             
      body: BlocListener<ConnBloc, ConnState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state.dioError != null) {
            MySnack.sError(
              context,
              state.dioError!,
            );
          }
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: pages[_selectedTab],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _botNavBar(context),
    );
  }

and the snackbar class is here:
class MySnack {
  static void sSucc(
    BuildContext context,
    String message,
  ) {
    _showSnackBar(
      context,
      message,
      Colors.green,
      Colors.white,
    );
  }

  static void sError(
    BuildContext context,
    String message,
  ) {
    _showSnackBar(
      context,
      message,
      Colors.red,
      Colors.white,
    );
  }

  static void _showSnackBar(
    BuildContext context,
    String message,
    Color backgroundColor,
    Color textColor,
  ) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        message,
        style: TextStyle(color: textColor),
      ),
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: 'Close',
        textColor: textColor,
        onPressed: () {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
        },
      ),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}

